# vba storage error while running

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error as msg as "Not enough storage is available to coplete this operation. Please advise as to how should i go ahead. i have restart the computer many time but still facing same proble.

```
On Error Resume Next

For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox5.ListCount - 1
If Me.ListBox5.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
Me.ListBox6.AddItem Me.ListBox5.List(iCtr)
End If
Next iCtr

For iCtr = Me.ListBox5.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
If Me.ListBox5.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
'Me.ListBox5.RemoveItem iCtr
End If
Next iCtr
```

Comment: You should probably be clearing Listbox6 before you add the new items. Also, is there any code behind listbox 6, and where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: I am gettting an error as " not enought storage is available to complete the operation" whenever the above code is executed. I am working on some prject have lots of frames and listview.

Comment: On a particular line? The rest doesn't really answer my questions I'm afraid.